# echoing php data

Tags: php, javascript, xml

in the following code , I have echoed $strXML in php file,which shows the whole $strXML but I want to show just the 'name' element values in javascript. Can anybody help me?

PHP :

```
$strXML = '<? xml version="1.0" ?>'."\n"; 

$id   = $_GET['id'];     
$name = $_GET['name'];     

$strXML .= '<data>'."\n";     
$strXML .= '<id>'.$id.'</id>'."\n";     
$strXML .= '<name>'.$name.'</name>'."\n";      
$strXML .= '</data>'."\n";        

echo $strXML;
```

javascript:

```
var xhr = createRequest();
function getData() {
    if(xhr) {
        var id  = document.getElementById("id").value;
        var name  = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var url = "search.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name;
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = show;
        xhr.send(null);
    } 
}


function show()
{
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4) &&(xhr.status == 200))   
    {        
        var strXML = xhr.responseText;   
        alert(strXML);  
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the structure of the XML?

Comment: could you use jquery? Would be easier. Also in this case json may even be easier as well. You can create an array and encode it on php side and then decode it on the javascript side. with jquery this would be very easy as well.

Comment: Debug your javascript using firebug or chrome development toold. Place a breakpoint in the function you included in your question and confirm that it's being executed.

Answer (score 1):

The [`responseText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-xmlhttprequest-interface) property is a string (a DOMString in the specification but that is just a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMString) in JavaScript) so you can't call [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) on it; you want to look at `xhr.responseXML`.

Also, `getElementsByTagName` searches beneath the element it is called on:

> The subtree underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element itself.

So you'll have to access the contents directly rather than inside a loop:

```
var result = xhr.responseXML;
var id     = result.getElementsByTagName('id'  ).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var name   = result.getElementsByTagName('name').childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

If you want to return multiple `<data>` elements (and hence, use your `for` loop) then you'll have to wrap the return value from your PHP in one more element:

```
<results>
    <data>
       <id>$id</id>
       <name>$name</name>
    </data>
    <!-- etc. -->
</results>
```

Comment: @neel: I'd guess that's because `result` is the `<data>` element itself, can you try `result.getElementsByTagName('id')`?

Comment: @neel: What Content-Type are you sending the XML back as? You should be using `text/xml` or `application/xml` if you want the `responseXML` object.

Comment: @neel: Your `onreadystatechange` should be like this: `xhr.onreadystatechange = show;` (note the lack of parentheses on `show`)' you don't want to call the function and assign its return value to `xhr.onreadystatechange`, you want to assign the function itself.

Comment: @mu is too short   yes u r right thats y i changed the code above , now its showing the strXML via alert( ).... but still cant get just 'name' element values in javascript?

Comment: @neel: Is anything in `responseXML` now that everything is wired up properly and you're sending back the right content type?

Comment: @mu is too short if i used responseXML instead of resposeText, it returns "[object XMLDocument]"

Comment: @neel: Cool, you should be able to use the `getElementsByTagName` method on `responseXML` then.

Comment: @mu is too short , i am still unable to get any data from responseXML   it returns null?

Comment: @neel: But you're getting an object in `responseText`, right? I think I misread your May 24 comment. If you're getting an `XMLDocument` object in `responseText` then you should be able to call `getElementsByTagName` on that.

Answer (score 1):

Not to criticize your current decision, but I've found that it's much easier to use a combination of PHP and JavaScript if you use JSON for transferring the data back and forth. PHP has excellent methods to create JSON, and JavaScript... well, it is JavaScript. I think this generally makes development a whole lot easier:

```
<?php   
$data = array(
    'data' => array(
        'id' => $_GET['id'],
        'name' => $_GET['name']
    )
);

echo json_encode( $data );
```

And on the JS side:

```
var xhr = createRequest();
function getData() {
    if(xhr) {
        var id  = document.getElementById("id").value;
        var name  = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var url = "search.php?id=" + id + "&name=" + name;
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = show();
        xhr.send(null);
    } 
}

function show()
{
    if ((xhr.readyState == 4) &&(xhr.status == 200))   
    {
        var response = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');
        alert( response.data.id );
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're already using the XML elsewhere (e.g. in a webservice, or using XSLT to show the page), XML would make more sense. Just my $0,02 though.

Comment: thanks for ur help but i cant use json as it is not in my requirement